# trying to get the last child in css, but it doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was curious as to why:

```
$("div.title").last();
```

does not return the same item as the css code:

`$("div.title:nth-child(0)")` or `$("div.title:last-child")`

im trying to reference it in css, but it seems that it doesnt seem to do it.

the html looks like:

```
<div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.last()` returns the last element that matches the selector, `:last-child` matches the element that matches the selector _and is the last child_.

Comment: Also, is there a reason why you are explicitly specifying `div` in all the selectors? That is somewhat against good practice.

Comment: `$("div.title:last")`...

Comment: `:last` doesnt seem to do what i want, well not in pure css using GoogleChrome anyways

Comment: no there isnt, i could just remove the `div` component i guess. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child` only applies to the last child of the parent (similar to the jQuery `.last()`)

However, the CSS `:last-of-type` selects the last occurrence of the pattern, which is probably what you were aiming to do:

`div.title:last-of-type` will select the same element as the jQuery `$("div.title").last();`

(note: both of these selectors do not work by default in IE8 or lower)

Comment: last-of-type is based entirely on the element type, not the prior defined selector (unless is it related purely to an element type

Comment: `div.title:last-of-type` will select the same element as your jQuery `$("div.title").last();` (ill add this to my answer)

Answer (score 6):

`:last-child` in CSS will only select the element if it is the last child of it's parent, regardless of element, class, or any other selector.

In jQuery `.last()` will actually filter on the collection of elements you got in your jQuery selector.

Comment: So if i wanted to get the answer of something such as my example, im guessing that I would need to add a id of sorts to the div wrapper?

Comment: Your options would be: 1. Add a class or ID to the last item. 2. Change the _type_ of element (i.e. section instead of div) and use `:last-of-type`. 3. Use jQuery

Comment: i think the leverage of the Section tag would be a really good option, though i guess i could just add a class to the last element if i wanted a copout.  I think ill utilize a section tag.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in CSS, `:last-child` refers to the last child of the parent. So for..

```
<div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="title"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

`div.title:last-child` will not select anything as the last child of `div.title`'s parent is a `div`.

`:nth-child(n)` works with the same logic. Here `n` refers to the index of each child of the parent starting the count from `1`.

`last()` of jQuery is different. It selects the last occurrence of the jQuery selector that has been provided. So, `$("div.title").last();` will select the last `div.title` in the entire code.

Comment: I mean, it makes sense, sure.  Im just trying to find some query which would do what i want.  Im trying to use more CSS in my code instead of jquery.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to use more of the CSS selectors in your jQuery selector?

Comment: yea, well, i mean i am doing some stylzing css, and want to abstract it from my Javascript so it can be more dynamically swapped out

Comment: In that case, using `:nth-child(n)` or `:nth-last-child(n)` seems to be the only way out, if you want to stick to CSS, as the second `div.title` is clearly not the `:last-child`